# My question is about Regular Expression in java

Tags: java, regex

I want to know the what will be the regular expression of the below scenario?

I want to find out the multi-line comments from my java code as below.

**Text 1::**

```
/*
This is my multi-line comment.
This is second line of the comment.
*/
```

But I do not want to find out the expression which is as below.

**Text 2::**

```
/**
Any method description.
*/
```

So, I just want to extract the comments which will be like Text 1 but not like Text 2.

I have tried this regex:

```
/*([^*]|[\r\n]|(*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))**+/
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: How about `/\*([^*](?:[^*]+|\*[^/])*)\*/`? See [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/LJbwhO/1) for demo.

Comment: Should it match exactly your example data and not other variations are possible? No spaces before or after `/*` and `*/` etc?

Answer (score 2):

When using e.g. online regex tools, when the whole regex is enclosed in
slashes, the regex required in your case is:

```
\/\*(?!\*).+?\*\/
```

Details:

- `\/` - A slash (quoted).
- `\*` - An asterrisk (also quoted).
- `(?!\*)` - Negative lookahead for an asterrisk (quoted).
- `.+?` - A non-empty sequence of any chars, reluctant version.
  Due to *DOTALL* option, this sequence includes also newline chars.
- `\*\/` - An asterrisk and a slash (both quoted).

But in Java context:

- The regex is **not** enclosed in slashes, so the slashes in regex need
  not be quoted.
- Any backslash must be written **twice**.

So the regex to be included in Java code should be rewritten to:

```
/\\*(?!\\*).+?\\*/
```

Below you have an example Java code, processing your source text:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Rextester {  
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String src = "/*\n" +
            "This is my multi-line comment.\n" +
            "This is second line of the comment.\n" +
            "*/\n" +
            "/**\n" +
            "Any method description.\n" +
            "*/";
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("/\\*(?!\\*).+?\\*/", Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(src);
        int cnt = 0;
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Found %d:\n%s", ++cnt, m.group()));
        }
    }
}
```

It prints:

```
Found 1:
/*
This is my multi-line comment.
This is second line of the comment.
*/
```

As you can see, just the first comment, omitting the second.

As an excercise, change `"/**\n"` in the above code to `"/* *\n"` (add
a space between asterrisks).
Then run your code and you will see that this time **both** comments
were printed, because the negative lookahead checks for an asterrisk
**immediately** following the first one.